# What's the difference between T1 and T2?

Tags: decoherence, terminology-and-notation

I learned that T1 is relaxation time (time from $|1\rangle$ to $|0\rangle$) and T2 is coherence time.
The relaxation is a specific case of decoherence.
What's the difference between them and what's the exact meaning of coherence time T2?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

T2 is so-called *dephasing time*.

It describes how long the phase of a qubit stays intact. In your words, it is time from $|+\rangle= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)$ to $|-\rangle= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)$, or conversely.

Just note that both T1 and T2 are not actually "time from state x to state y" but rather decay constants. Probability that a qubit will stay in state $|1\rangle$ after time $t$ is given by formula

$$
P(|1\rangle) = \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{t}{T1}}.
$$

Similarly for T2.

Both times T1 and T2 are together called *decoherence times*.

Answer (score 27):

Slight correction to Martin Vesely's answer: $T_2$ is not the (decay constant) time after which an initial state $|+\rangle$ will necessarily switch to the state $|-\rangle$. If it were, then error correction would be easy. Instead, it's the (decay constant) time after which an initial state $|+\rangle$ will evolve into an equal classical probabilistic mixture of the $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$ states, so that you can no longer confidently predict the state. That is, it's the autocorrelation time after which the initial and final states become uncorrelated, not negatively correlated.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.

Comment: +1 to this answer - a good explanation can be found here as well, I think it is helpful to see the "how do you measure it" and "how the curves typically look like": https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-435j-quantum-computation-fall-2003/lecture-notes/qc_lec19.pdf